# SSO for Mobile App and login to Salesforce

Tags: single-sign-on

We have mobile app now use SOAP API directly login to SFDC.
Now we want to use SSO, user will click a button go to their own system first in mobile side and then input their username and password, when login, it will return to SFDC. How to acheived this ?

Comment: Check this link https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth

Comment: I checked this, but the way in the blog mentioned are both use salesforce standard login page, for the customized page how should we do?